# How to make sap.f.GridList scrollable inside a control Panel?

Tags: sapui5

I'm adding some GenericTile based on my model into a `sap.f.GridList`. This is successful. But my problem is that I don't want to have my whole page to be scrollable but only the GridList. That is the reason I add a Panel control and a TileContent.

What did I make wrong? Do you have any suggestion to achieve that?

[image]

Here is my code:

```xml
<Panel>
  <TileContent footerColor="Good" frameType="OneByOne">
    <f:GridList xmlns:f="sap.f" id="FormPart4" headerText="Liste des Cartons" items="{CartonsList&gt;/results}" growing="true" noDataText="Aucunes données disponible">
      <f:customLayout>
        <cssgrid:GridBoxLayout xmlns:cssgrid="sap.ui.layout.cssgrid" boxMinWidth="17rem" />
      </f:customLayout>
      <f:GridListItem navigated="true">
        <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" shrinkFactor="0" />
          </layoutData>
          <GenericTile header="Carton N°: " press="onCarton_Click" headerImage="sap-icon://palette">
            <TileContent>
              <NumericContent value="{CartonsList&gt;Number}" withMargin="true" truncateValueTo="24" />
            </TileContent>
          </GenericTile>
        </VBox>
      </f:GridListItem>
    </f:GridList>
  </TileContent>
</Panel>
```

Comment: i wouldnt use a panel for this usecase if i understood you right. You can use a scrollcontainer instead of  a panel.  So basicly: a box and make the content scrollable. 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.ScrollContainer

Comment: Thank you **@Jünge alles**. i did as you suggest and it's working. Thank you for your help

Comment: @LionelSamstag. Please post the solution as an answer and accept it to let others know that the issue is resolved.